# Forcing 32bit compilation on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: mac-osx, configuration

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.

How do I force configure to compile in 32 bit mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply set the CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS :

```
export CFLAGS=-m32

export CPPFLAGS=-m32
```

These flags will simply force `gcc` to use the `-m32` option, which compiles into 32 bits mode.

So if you only have one file to compile, you can use:

```
gcc -m32 myfile.c
```